# AngularJS: How to right-click a link to download file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml

I would like to be able to not just display xml but also have an option to download file from server.

In html, clicking the icon will execute download function:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" ng-click="download(report.filename)"></span>
```

download function is defined in my controller.js

```
   $scope.download = function(filename) {
        fmFactory.getXMLFile(filename).then(function (response) {
            var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/xml'});
            var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            $window.open(fileURL, '_blank', 'width=700, height=800');
        });
    }
```

With this implementation I am able to display the file content (in this case xml) in a new pop-up window. However when I right click the icon and choose to save as a file, it only saves as the html. How do I make it download the actual xml file?

**EDIT**:
I also tried to provide just the link to the file without making any requests to webservices. The folder that contains all the files are inside [tomcat]/webapps/data/fm, webapps is where war (ristoreService.war) is deployed in.

[image]

So now my html becomes:

```
<a ng-href="http://rcdrljboss01a:9880/ristoreService/data/fm/{{report.filename}}.xml">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></a>
```

When I launch the webpage and click on the link, it redirects to `http://rcdrljboss01a:9880/ristoreService/data/fm/TRF011063_08042016001105.xml` and shows error `Full authentication is required to access this resource` in xml format, see picture below:

[image]

I did secure the website with oauth and spring security. Authentication is done at login and access_token is saved for all http requests afterwards. But with href, it does not communicate with webservice at all. As long as the user who is running tomcat instance, which is `risdev`, has permission to access the file, it should work. As a matter of fact, user `risdev` does have read permission to the file location.

I turned on the development tool in chrome and error of the page is quite confusing: "failed to read localStorage". Why does it have to do with localStorage?
[image]

Comment: turn it into an anchor tag with an href that links to the file you want to download.

Comment: You need `<a href=...` and a real server URL to be able to properly support right-click save-as. It's how browsers work and you can't change it. You'd have implement custom right click menu (by preventing the native one, and displaying yours instead) to work around it (and it's not a good choice to do so).

Comment: @jakub.g couldn't get href to work due to an odd error. See more details in my edits.

Comment: @ddd error seems pretty obvious.

Comment: @KevinB Not too obvious to me. First of all, I am logged in as myself `djiao`. Since this link does not have anything to do with web service, it should not need oauth authentication. It is the user `risdev` who runs the tomcat instance accessing the file with the link. Evidently `risdev` has been granted access to the files. Why not authorized?

Comment: Server isn't giving you access to it. Either lift permissions, get properly authenticated, or move it to a less secure area.

Comment: @KevinB, like I said, permission is not an issue, I can open that file without any prob logged in as `risdev` using command line on the server. What do you mean "properly authenticated", I clicked on the link after I logged in on the page (oauth authentication succeeded). In the same session, I can do any operation that makes ajax calls to the web service. It is just this link does not work

Comment: *"permission is not an issue"* If that were true, you wouldn't be getting an unauthorized access error. You are passing something along with the ajax requests that likely isn't (and can't be) getting passed along with the anchor tag click.

Comment: All this trouble just to let the user be able to right click in addition to left.

Comment: @KevinB that is correct, ajax calls need access_token provided in the request header. But the link is merely href, it has nothing to do with the web service. The url is not a legit rest url that has a corresponding controller anyway, why does it need the same authentication? Oauth is only implemented in the webservice.

Comment: It's your server that is denying access.. how am i supposed to know.

Comment: @KevinB I started to think, the url for the link is wrong. This prefix `http://rcdrljboss01a:9880/ristoreService/` is actually pointing to the webapp (war is called ristoreService). Since I placed the folder of the files under [tomcat]/webapps/ which is the same level as the war, I guess the url should be `http://rcdrljboss01a:9880/data/fm/xxx.xml`. Tried that, now getting tomcat error "resource not available". At least it has nothing to do with authentication now which makes sense. It is also proof my url is not correct, what should be the right url for this case?

Comment: @KevinB Can you turn your comments into an official answer so I can close it? Thanks.